# Access VBA - Assigning a value to duplicate records?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a table with products taken from an Excel spreadsheet and some have duplicate values in the 'Product ID' field. Where this happens I want to assign a value to differentiate between them in the 'Run No' field. So for example it would look like this...

```
Product ID|Run No|ProcessNo |Product Description
34        |  1   |71808013  |Product 1
34        |  2   |71807961  |Product 1
42        |  1   |71808011  |Product 2
42        |  2   |71807962  |Product 2
43        |  1   |71808012  |Product 3
41        |  1   |71807959  |Product 4
52        |  1   |71808010  |Product 5
52        |  2   |71807960  |Product 5
```

The products that will appear in this table will change every day and could have more than 2 runs. I've tried looking around for solutions but the closest thing was for Excel (http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=46060) and I don't really understand how I could implement that in Access. So far I've only managed to find the duplicates using a query but I'm a little lost after that.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the run number with something like:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from mytable as t2
        where t2.productid = t.productid and
              t2.processno <= t.processno
       ) as runno
from mytable as t;
```

This assumes that `processno` is distinct for any given product, which is the case for your sample data.